# what is the 'en' under those XIB files in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xib

I'm looking at a sample code from Apple; named 'iPhoneCoreDataRecipes' and found those 'en' files under DetailHeaderView.xib, RecipeAddView.xib and InstructionsView.xib.

Wonder what are they and their purpose.

Why just make one DetailHeaderView.xib file without the 'en' file?

please find the capture screen shot from the link below:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wulc1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for localization. 'en' means English. You could have other files for other languages.

Comment: oh cheers Thilo!~. then...I guess it'd be ok to make, for example , DetailHeaderView.xib alone (like normal case)without the en file? (if there is no need for localization)